# What is the singular value decomposition of a matrix with size 1 x m?

Tags: linear-algebra

This should be a really really simple question but I'm struggling.

suppose you have:

$ y = M x $

and $M$ is $1 \times m$

$ y = U \Sigma V x$

$U$ should be a scalar, $\Sigma$ should be $1 \times m$ and $V$ should be $m \times m$.

Now I want to write $\Sigma = M$ and $V = $ Identity matrix.

This, however, doesn't look right since $\Sigma$ needs to be diagonal..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your $M$ is in real space. In this case, $U,V$ would be all real. Since your $M$ is of dimension $1\times m$. It is of rank 1 if it is not a $\vec{0}$ and thus the singular value is just its two norm $\sigma=\sqrt{MM^T}$. Then the $U=1$ and $\Sigma = [\sigma,0,0,..0]$ and $$V= \begin{bmatrix} \frac{M}{\sigma} \\ v_2\\v_3\\ \vdots \\v_m\end{bmatrix} $$ where $M/\sigma,v_i$ are all row orthonormal vectors.

Comment: $V$ should be a unitary matrix of dimension $m\times m$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

Comment: @JankoBracic, I think evan54 just means real space and in this case unitary would be simply orthonormal. It is not hard to get the complex case when one understands the real case.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\Sigma$ should be the diagonal matrix with singular values of $M$ on the diagonal.
Note that the singular values are square roots of eigenvalues of $MM^*$ which is in this case a nonnegative number. Hence $\Sigma=\left[ \sqrt{M M^*}\quad 0 \quad \ldots \quad 0\right]$.
$U$ can be number $1$ and $V$ $m\times m$ unitary such that $\Sigma V=M$.

Comment: since $M$ is a row vector, I think you mean $MM^*$.

Comment: Correct, I will edit! Thanks!